# Why is the magnetic field outside a solenoid considered zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

While applying Ampere's  law to derive the magnetic field of a solenoid,
why can we consider $\vec{\bf B }$ to be zero just outside the solenoid?
For example [here](https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2000fall/PHY232/lectures/ampereslaw/solenoid.html) it says "Only the upper portion of the path contributed to the sum because the magnetic field is zero outside..". What is the proper justification for this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an *infinite* solenoid, you can argue by symmetry that the $B$-field outside the solenoid has to be parallel to the axis. From this, by varying the size of the loop used in Ampere's law, you can show that the $B$-field outside the solenoid (whatever strength it is) does not vary with distance from the solenoid.

It's pretty easy to show that the $B$-field goes to zero from a solenoid, even an infinite one, as the distance from the solenoid goes to infinity. And so the $B$-field has to be *uniformly* zero outside the solenoid.

For a *finite* solenoid, if you  are not close to the ends, you can argue that the missing parts of the infinite solenoid shouldn't affect the $B$-field much, and so the field is weak outside the solenoid as compared to inside.

Comment: I strongly believe this is wrong. Even an infinite solenoid.would.produce.a magnetic field similiar (even the same) like.a wire with.the same current. Or do.you think a current clamp.wouldnt.work for this arrangement.

Comment: @lalala the field is constant outside by Ampere's law.  It must be $0$ for otherwise a finite current would produce a non-zero field at $\infty$.  In particular, given that the magnetic energy density $\sim \vert \vec B\vert^2$, this would in turn imply that a finite current can produce an infinite amount of energy (once the energy density is integrated over the whole space).  Indeed one can numerically show that the field becomes arbitrarily small at the waist of an arbitrary long solenoid *if the coil windings are tights*.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's not a valid argument. It takes infinite energy to get a finite current going in an infinite cylinder (since its inductance is infinite), and the energy integrated over space is infinite anyway (since an infinite solenoid has infinite volume). You have to be more careful with an energy argument here...

Comment: @lalala That said, the result is correct. It's an elementary result you should be able to read about in an E&M textbook.

Comment: Question is: in your abstraction of the infinite solenoid, is the a current going from minus infinity to plus infinity (then there is a magnetic field outside (due to.Amperes law), with the same strength a straight wire of the same.current. or do you think.of a charged cylinder rotating. To me, an.infinite solenoid is the former.

Comment: @lalala You are just wrong. A solenoid is a coil- the current does not travel in a straight line, but in a curved path. Realistically a helical path, although typically calculations are done with a bunch of circular loops. There is no sensible way you can treat a solenoid as a straight wire.

Comment: Maybe I wrote too short. I agree, it travels in a straight path. So.take any disc perpenticular to the direction of the axis solenoid (if the solenoid.goes from minus infinity to plus.infinity in the z direction, then any disc paralell.to.the xy plane), and calculate the current through it. This 'forward moving' current is the same current as in the wire making the solenoid, lets call it I. If you now apply Amperes law that disc, you find the outside of an infinite eokenoud has the same magnetic field as a wire with current I.

Comment: @lalala No, it *doesn't* travel in a straight path. That's the opposite of what I said. The *actual* path of the current matters, not just the direction.

Comment: Well, it does not matter. All current has to go to the xy plane eventually to reach the other half.

Comment: @Chris I understood that the magnetic field is uniform outside as well as inside, But why do we say that magnetic field is uniformly 0, this is the part that I don't understand, Can you please elaborate on this part?

Comment: @lalala It's instructive to consider the differential form of Ampere's law: $\nabla\times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J}$, where $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density. To recover the integral form: $\int \nabla\times \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{a} = \mu_0 \int \mathbf{J} \cdot d \mathbf{a}$. As the coils become very tightly wound, the current density $\mathbf{J}$ tends towards being parallel to your surface of integration. Therefore, just as Chris stated, the direction of the current **is** important, but this is not obvious from the conventional integral formula.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there has to be some magnetic field outside the solenoid as well, but that magnetic field is so weak that it is not considered for theoretical purposes.

What actually matters is the Magnetic Flux. Inside a solenoid the magnetic flux is too high (large number of magnetic field lines crossing a small cross-sectional area) whereas, outside the solenoid, the spacing between the field lines increases, i.e., the number of lines crossing per unit area reduces considerably. Thus, in comparison to inside volume of a solenoid, the magnetic field outside the solenoid is relatively zero. You can include that magnetic field in your calculation but that would make the mathematics little more difficult.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a proper reasoning to show that the field outside is weak. Does this follow from some kind of symmetry argument?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07876

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked long ago but here is the correct explanation for the newcomers

1. The magnetic flux outside the solenoid is considered to be zero. This is only considered to be 0 but it is not zero it has some values.
   2.It is considered to be zero because the number of magnetics lines of forces passing
   from outside through a cross section of a solenoid, is less as compared to number of lines passing through the inner part of the solenoid. Or the magnetic flux of outside is very low in comparison with the inner side.